# How is the DataContext typically set?

Tags: wpf

I've created a new WPF project, and threw in a DataGrid. Now I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to bind a collection of data to it.

The example I downloaded seems to do it in the window c'tor:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

But then the bindings don't seem to appear in the Visual Studio's Properties window. I'm pretty sure there's a way to set the data context in XAML too... it would make me even happier if I could do it directly through the properties window, but all the Binding options are empty. What's the typical approach?

**Edit:** [At 14 minutes](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=315275), he starts to talk about other methods of setting the data context, such as static resources, and some "injection" method. I want to learn more about those!

Comment: It seems its easiest to set the `DataContext` in the code-behind, because you'll often want to have a bunch of code that modifies it... this way you don't have to keep retrieving the DataContext at casting it to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 3):

What I typically do is use [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). You can implement a simplified version by setting the data context in your code behind and having a model type class that holds your data.

Example: In your code behind

```
DataContext = Model; // where Model is an instance of your model
```

then in your view

```
<DataGrid .... ItemsSource="{Binding SomeProperty}">....
```

Where `SomeProperty` is an enumerable property on your view model

You can also set a data context in XAML by using the `DataContext` property

```
<uc:SomeUserControl DataContext="{Binding AnotherProperty}"....
```

This will run your user control within the `DataContext` of the `AnotherProperty` on your model.

Note that this is grosely simplified but it'll get you on your way.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [MVVM design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). This pattern is very suitable for wpf applications.

There is described where to store your data and how to bind your ui to the data.

Comment: Was hoping for a quick answer, not another monster tutorial ;) I've read about MVVM wrt ASP .NET MVC, but I specifically want to know how to bind the data such that it works with the properties window.